# Facebook login for an app with subdomains

Tags: facebook, oauth

Since the "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" became obligatory I have an issue with my application.
It uses the

> user.myapp.com

schema to allow different users to log inte their "work area".
But while the list of the users is dynamic, I cannot modify the Client OAuth Settings every time a new user is added.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: No, there is not. You need to find another solution that doesn’t require an unlimited amount of domains/redirect URIs to begin with.

Comment: Handle the login on a single domain, and then send the user to their specific subdomain.

Comment: I have tried the @JonathonReinhart 's solution. There is a problem with some data from session/local storage: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.